# Where can I find the "queryparametertemplate.xml" file?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, jsom, sharepoint-search

Trying to get Search API working for anonymous.  I believe i need to update this file with my `Site ID`.  Does anyone know where it is located so I can edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the XML file and upload it to the site collection. please see below.

[Configuring SharePoint 2013 Search for anonymous users](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/configuring-sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api-anonymous-users/)

**To enable anonymous Search REST queries**

Enable anonymous access on the web application and publishing site. For more information about how to do this, see Manage permission policies for a web application in SharePoint 2013 and Plan for user authentication methods in SharePoint 2013 on TechNet.

- Add a new document library named QueryPropertiesTemplate to the
  publishing site.
- Create an XML file named queryparametertemplate.xml, and copy the
  following XML to the file.

**XML**

```
<QueryPropertiesTemplate xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sharepoint/search/KnownTypes/2008/08" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <QueryProperties i:type="KeywordQueryProperties">
        <EnableStemming>true</EnableStemming>
        <FarmId>FarmID</FarmId>
        <IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>true</IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>
        <KeywordInclusion>AllKeywords</KeywordInclusion>
        <SiteId>SiteID</SiteId>
        <SummaryLength>180</SummaryLength>
        <TrimDuplicates>true</TrimDuplicates>
        <WcfTimeout>120000</WcfTimeout>
        <WebId>WebID</WebId>
        <Properties xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                <a:Key>_IsEntSearchLicensed</a:Key>
                <a:Value i:type="b:boolean" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">true</a:Value>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                <a:Key>EnableSorting</a:Key>
                <a:Value i:type="b:boolean" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">true</a:Value>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                <a:Key>MaxKeywordQueryTextLength</a:Key>
                <a:Value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">4096</a:Value>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                <a:Key>TryCache</a:Key>
                <a:Value i:type="b:boolean" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">true</a:Value>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
        </Properties>
        <PropertiesContractVersion>15.0.0.0</PropertiesContractVersion>
        <EnableFQL>false</EnableFQL>
        <EnableSpellcheck>Suggest</EnableSpellcheck>
        <EnableUrlSmashing>true</EnableUrlSmashing>
        <IsCachable>false</IsCachable>
        <MaxShallowRefinementHits>100</MaxShallowRefinementHits>
        <MaxSummaryLength>185</MaxSummaryLength>
        <MaxUrlLength>2048</MaxUrlLength>
        <SimilarType>None</SimilarType>
        <SortSimilar>true</SortSimilar>
        <TrimDuplicatesIncludeId>0</TrimDuplicatesIncludeId>
        <TrimDuplicatesKeepCount>1</TrimDuplicatesKeepCount>
    </QueryProperties>
    <WhiteList xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:string>RowLimit</a:string>
        <a:string>SortList</a:string>
        <a:string>StartRow</a:string>
        <a:string>RefinementFilters</a:string>
        <a:string>Culture</a:string>
        <a:string>RankingModelId</a:string>
        <a:string>TrimDuplicatesIncludeId</a:string>
        <a:string>ReorderingRules</a:string>
        <a:string>EnableQueryRules</a:string>
        <a:string>HiddenConstraints</a:string>
        <a:string>QueryText</a:string>
        <a:string>QueryTemplate</a:string>
    </WhiteList>
</QueryPropertiesTemplate>
```

- Update the SiteId, FarmId, and WebId elements with the values for
  your farm, website and publishing site collection.
- Save queryparametertemplate.xml to the QueryPropertiesTemplate
  document library.
- Add the QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl parameter to your Search REST
  call, specifying spfile://webroot/queryparametertemplate.xml as the
  value.

**queryparametertemplate.xml file**

The primary elements in the queryparametertemplate.xml file are:

- QueryProperties element

  Contains a serialized QueryProperties object.
- WhiteList element

  Contains the list of query properties that the anonymous user is allowed to set.
  When an anonymous Search REST query is submitted, the query object is constructed using what's specified in the QueryProperties element. Then, all the properties that are listed in the whitelist are copied from the incoming query to the newly constructed query object.

Comment: This is still not returning results. I'm getting a 500 error.

Comment: this answer is about the .xml files, if you have the issue with using it...then may be raise another question with error details....

Comment: The link in the answer does not take to the intended page.